# Is there a way to make a LaTeX environment where indentation is interpreted as itemize levels?

Tags: latex

As much as I like LaTeX, I find it rather annoying (and visually noisy) that itemize and enumerate environments always require (1) the begin/end environment declaration statements, and (2) "\item" commands prior to each item.

What I'd love to have (or be able to create) is some kind of "autoitemize" environment, where something like

```
\begin{autoitemize}
  first item
  second item
    nested item
    another nested item
  third item
\end{autoitemize}
```

would be automatically translated to:

```
\begin{itemize}
  \item first item
  \item second item
  \begin{itemize}
    \item nested item
    \item another nested item
  \end{itemize}
  \item third item
\end{itemize}
```

So the question:  is there a way to do this using a LaTeX package, rather than with an external preprocessor?

It might also be nice to be able to have some sort of optional line prefix on the item-lines which indicates what kind of list environment the item and its successors is in -- this would allow for nesting of one type within another.

Granted, this may not be as powerful as just doing it the normal LaTeX way, but there are enough cases where it would be sufficient and quite handy.

Comment: Migrate to http://tex.stackexchange.com/?

Answer (score 2):

That's what Markdown and Restructured Text (RST) are for.  You're not really talking about LaTeX any more, when you ask this.  You're asking about a different markup language.

From RST you can easily generate LaTeX for publication purposes.

http://docutils.sourceforge.net/rst.html

Comment: RST is good for a variety of documents, but it lacks the power and range of packages available for LaTeX -- it's true that it can be exported to LaTeX, but I'd really prefer to keep everything *within* a LaTeX source file.  Some kind of automatic ReST to LaTeX inline conversion would be ok, but I'm not aware of anything like this.

Comment: I use automatic RST to LaTeX all the time.  And the inlines convert very nicely.  `rst2latex.py` comes with docutils and works marvelously well.  I'm not sure what you can't do, but I'm absolutely sure it generates very nice LaTeX and simplifies my life a great deal.

Comment: Update: I said in my previous comment "I'm not aware of anything like this".  Well, now I am: Pweave (https://bitbucket.org/edgimar/pweave/src) -- this basically allows including and automatic preprocessing/replacement of any kind of inline block in a textfile (e.g. one could use rst2latex.py in combination w/Pweave to automatically do inline substitution of rst within a LaTeX document).

Comment: @Mark: "I'd really prefer to keep everything within a LaTeX source file" doesn't make sense to me, since the content you're showing is not actually LaTeX.  Making the "within a LaTeX" file very confusing to me.

Comment: Yes, that is correct -- it isn't pure LaTeX in the sense that it can be directly compiled with pdflatex/etc.  It is technically possible to write such a file with a customized style-file, but one must run pdflatex in write18 mode, which isn't ideal for portable LaTeX source files (portable meaning that minimal special dependencies / flags are required).  With pweave, the executable and processor-plugins can easily be bundled along with the sourcefile, making it relatively portable.

Answer (score 0):

[Emacs Org mode](http://orgmode.org/) might allow you to do something like this. It has some capacity to translate into LaTeX.